# AWS Amplify React build failed Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, aws-amplify

I have created a normal React project via the CLI and am currently getting a build error on AWS Amplify and pointing to a svg file.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file
```

I've not manually added web pack to my project so why is this error occurring? If I run npm start build locally everything is working fine.

This are my dependencies in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^1.2.5",
"@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
"@craco/craco": "^6.1.2",
"@headlessui/react": "^1.2.0",
"@heroicons/react": "^1.0.1",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
"@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.3",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
"aws-amplify": "^4.1.3",
"date-fns": "^2.22.1",
"formik": "^2.2.9",
"i18next": "^20.3.2",
"initials": "^3.1.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"next": "^10.2.0",
"next-preload-headers": "^3.0.4",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-feather": "^2.0.9",
"react-i18next": "^11.11.0",
"react-mega-menu": "^1.0.1",
"react-progressbar": "^15.4.1",
"react-router": "^5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"react-spinners": "^0.11.0",
"react-table": "^7.7.0",
"web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
"yup": "^0.32.9"
```

},